# How to put position fixed child on top of the position fixed parent's scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, css-position, overlapping

I have to elements that have position fixed. One is the other's child.
I am using this structure for a resizable dropdown that is positioned in a left menu.

My problem is that if I the left menu has the overflow set to scroll/ auto the scrollbar is displayed on top of the child element.
How can I make the child element to be on top of the parent's scrollbar without changing the structure?

```css
.leftmenu {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  position:fixed;
  background-color: red;
  padding:20px;
  overflow:scroll;
}

.child {
  position:fixed;
  background-color:blue;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftmenu">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With `position: fixed` this won't be possible without moving the child outside of the parent. If you have the option of changing this, you could remove `position: fixed` from the parent and use `100vh` as the height of the leftmenu. Then change the child to `position: absolute` to bring it over the parent.

```css
.leftmenu {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftmenu">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your solution, but unfortunately I can't alter the leftmenu or the elements structure.

Comment: So your only option is changing the child class?

Comment: Yes, my only option is changing the child class.